# Listview in vanilla function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter more than one objects from model Offer_description

```
    shop = models.ShopProfile.objects.filter(shop_name=pk)
    shop_offers = models.Offer_description.objects.filter(shop_name=pk)
```

second query is not returning objects rather just names of objects.

```
<QuerySet [<ShopProfile: ShopProfile object (ddd)>]>
<QuerySet [<Offer_description: ddd>, <Offer_description: ddd>]>
```

model.py

```
class Offer_description(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    offer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="old")
    text = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="/media/off2.jpg")
    photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=False, default="/media/off2.jpg")
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,related_name='offers',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    ready_post = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes', default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name

    def get_like_url(self):
        return reverse("interface:like-toggle", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_api_like_url(self):
        return reverse("interface:like-api-toggle", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index")
```

views.py

```
def Shop_profile(request,pk):
    shop = models.ShopProfile.objects.filter(shop_name=pk)
    shop_offers = models.Offer_description.objects.get(shop_name=pk)

    print(shop_offers)
    print(shop)

return render(request,"shop_profile.html",{"shop":shop[0],"shop_offers":list(shop_offers)})
    return HttpResponse("done")
```

trying to have a list of all the offers by a particular shop along with shop details.

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. `shop_offers` contains the objects, you can *iterate* over the collection, like `for shop_offer in shop_offers: ...`. The `<Offer_description: ddd>` is just a *textual representation* of that object.

Comment: I want to render html template like {{shop_offer.offer_name}} which is showing nothing , i think it should be <ShopProfile: ShopProfile object (ddd)>

Comment: Can you share the `Offder_description` model? How do you call the render function?

Comment: hey thanks for your support actually i had made typing error in html template